# Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority "xxx"

Tags: azure-devops, ssl-certificate, integration-testing

We have a SSL certificate stored in Azure KeyVault. I have a PowerShell script that can connect to that KV, retrieve a certificate, add a password and import new generated certificate object into CurrentUser/My cert store on local machine.

Now, we have integration tests that use mentioned certificate to connect to 3rd party API. Locally all tests work fine and connection is established.

Then, I move solution along with PS script into VSTS build. One of the build steps is to run that PS script and import certificate from Azure to agent build machine. Next step is to run integration tests. And - voila - they all fail since cannot establish SSL connection to 3rd party API.

Exception:

`"ExceptionMessage":"Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'xxx'`

I have spent a day trying to investigate this issue, but no luck. Please advise.

Comment: can you share your powershell script and the build definition?

Comment: Seems this is not an issue with PS script of build definition. From what we have discovered this is either SSL server-to-server certificate problem or firewall settings. Have no idea how to check where is the problem since VSTS build agent seems a really black box. Server to server handshake isn't happening.

Comment: Do you use Hosted agent or Private agent?

Comment: Initially I've been using private agent and I thought it may have some restrictions to communicate with outer world. But then I switched to Hosted VS2017 build agent and nothing has changed. Got the same error.